# ASP.NET Core MVC. Реализация интерфейса IDataProtectionKeyContext

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Есть контекст данных:

```
public class OurDbContext : DbContext, IOurDbContext, IDataProtectionKeyContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    
    public DbSet<DataProtectionKey> DataProtectionKeys { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Есть метод, который реализует отправку данных в БД:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateNewClient(Employee client, string TypeOfClient)
{
    var secstring = _protector.Protect(client.Password);

    Employee temp = new Employee
    {
        Name = client.Name,
        Password = secstring,
        RoleId = 1
    };
    await _mediatr.Send(new NewEmployee.NewEmployeeCommand(temp));
    return Redirect("~/");
}
```

В БД не попадает ничего.

Если убрать из класса контекста реализацию `IDataProtectionKeyContext`

```
public DbSet<DataProtectionKey> DataProtectionKeys { get; set; } = null!;
```

и сократить строчку с

```
builder.Services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToDbContext<OurDbContext>();
```

до

```
builder.Services.AddDataProtection();
```

то данные попадают в БД с зашифрованным паролем. Но в таком случае, уже через 5 минут попытка прочитать этот пароль вызовет исключение из-за устаревшего ключа.

В справке Майкрософт ничего по этому поводу не сказано:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-6.0#persistkeystodbcontext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Говоря коротко, я попробовал сменить контекст с PostgreSQL на MS SQL и Sqlite и в них всё работает хорошо при той конфигурации, которая рекомендует Майкрофост в своей справке.